# Understanding the pattern "〜から、〜に耳打ちしてもらう"

Tags: particle-に, particle-から, giving-and-receiving

I am trying to interpret the sentence:

```
――ラファから、長に、そう耳打ちしてもらう
```

You can see this in context [here](http://ncode.syosetu.com/n4891y/), but I'll describe a little of the situation in this post.

The line is said by a character named Ian to the main character. The topic is Yakt, someone who broke a tradition of their culture. Ian had just told the MC "掟を破った者を、置いてはおけない。" which I believe means "We can't keep someone here who broke our rule."

ラファ (Rafa) seems to be a young girl who appears throughout the novel, and I assume 長 is the leader of the tribe (an older woman).

Anyway, I believe "耳打ち" means "whisper". So the crux of my question is how から and に fit in grammatically here with "してもらう"

I am guessing this sentence means the following:

```
Rafa will covertly tell the village chief about Yakt leaving the village.
```

However I may have things reversed.

Can someone confirm my interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read the whole thing, so I can't confirm the "about Yakt leaving the village" part, but what I read it seems like your interpretation is pretty much correct.

～してもらう is being used to convey that it'll further their purposes (in protecting the law or whatever), so a slightly more precise translation might be along the lines of "**we'll have** Rafa tell the chief XXX" depending on how/why Rafa ends up doing the telling. Additionally, depending on how Rafa is doing the telling, you could render 耳打ち more literally as "whisper." Again, context.